# Can't launch Activity in ActivityUnitTestCase

Tags: android, testing, activityunittestcase

I have been trying to launch a simple `Activity` from a `ActivityUnitTestCase`, without any success. I guess I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what it is... I managed to run Activities from `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, but not from `ActivityUnitTestCase`. The Activity I try to start contains a single Button which launches another Activity when clicked.

First, here is my code for `ActivityUnitTestCase`:

```
public class TestingActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<TestingActivity> {

    private Intent startIntent;

    public TestingActivityTest() {
        super(TestingActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        startIntent = new Intent(getInstrumentation()
                .getTargetContext(), TestingActivity.class);

    }

    public void testLaunchingSubActivity() {
        startActivity(startIntent, null, null);
        View button = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.forward_button);
        button.performClick();
        assertNotNull(getStartedActivityIntent());
        assertTrue(isFinishCalled());
    }
}
```

When I run this Test, I get these errors:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError at
>   junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:48) at
>   junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20) at
>   junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:218) at
>   junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:211) at
>   android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase.startActivity(ActivityUnitTestCase.java:147)
>   at
>   com.test.temp.TestingActivityTest.setUp(TestingActivityTest.java:27)
>   at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132) at
>   junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115) at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133) at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.DelegatingTestResult.runProtected(DelegatingTestResult.java:90)
>   at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118) at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestResult.run(AndroidTestResult.java:49)
>   at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124) at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.NonLeakyTestSuite$NonLeakyTest.run(NonLeakyTestSuite.java:63)
>   at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243) at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238) at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.DelegatingTestSuite.run(DelegatingTestSuite.java:103)
>   at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestSuite.run(AndroidTestSuite.java:63)
>   at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:90)
>   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:54)
>   at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:228)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1741)

The test fails when it tries to launch the Activity. I used a code very similar to this [documentation page](http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-unit-testing.html#testcase).

Thank you

Comment: So why are you not using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`? You can use an `ActivityMonitor` to check if your button started the other activity as expected. A guess for your issue is that you may need to run your `button.performClick();` from the UI thread, i.e. with `runOnUiThread(action);`.

Comment: Hi. In fact the line button.preformClick() is not reached. The line that throws the Exception is : startActivity(startIntent, null, null);

Comment: I added @UiThreadTest And it works fine now. Apparently startActivity must be ran on the main thread too.

Comment: Good idea, nice it works now.